# Relocating config files of depending assemblies

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, configuration, nlog

My application uses [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) as a logging framework hidden behind a facade in MyLogging project. The project is referenced by a number of web sites to not make them directly dependent on NLog. After compilation `NLog.config` from the logging project ends up in `bin` folders of each site and NLog manages to find it automatically during startup. That is understandable and pretty much OK. However, editing *any* file within `bin` folder forces ASP.NET to restart the working process so I'd like to have `NLog.config` one folder up beside regular `web.config`.

Things I'm trying to achieve\avoid:

1. Keep NLog configuration in a single file `cause it's the same for all of my web sites
2. Not to embed it into sites `web.config` (to not trigger ASP.NET auto-restart)
3. Just moving the file after building projects with msbuild command is not an option because the sites are deployed to Azure (moved files won't be packaged during publishing process)
4. I'd like to avoid messing with post-deployment scripts and hard coding things like `E:\siteroot\0`

The issue is not actually NLog specific as I'd have same trouble with standard `app.config` files. What are my options here?

Comment: keeping the nlog.config next to your web.config (so same directory), should work (I use it all the time). Why is this giving issues with you?

Comment: That's what I'd like to get because after the compilation NLog.config is in bin folder (its BuildAction is set to Content).

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET applications, it's recommend to set:

- "Build Action" to "content". Otherwise it won't be copied to the root folder (folder with web.config)
- "copy to Output Directory" to "none". Otherwise it will be copied to your bin folder.

See:

[image]

Comment: That would work if the config file was part of ASP.NET project and it's not. It's a content of another project (a class library) which is referenced by the web project.

Comment: You could add the file as linked file in VS?